# I want to find some files that includes some keyword and copy it to other folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to find files that includes some keyword and copy it to other folder.

So I need two features.

1. Find files by keyword and list it at "file" type value.
2. copy the file to different directory.

But Google drive supports same folder name so I don't know how to targeting folder by name. And I want copy the file only if there is not file has same name. Because I'll run this script every 5 minutes and if I don't set about that, there are many same name files to target directory.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm looking for tutorial of google site but I can't find how I can find any folder with codes.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only supported methods that you can use to get files in [Class DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) are:

- [getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String))
- [getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFiles())
- [getFilesByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String))
- [getFilesByType(mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByType(String))

Then, to make a copy to other folder, you can use the following methods that are given in [Class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file)

- [makeCopy(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(Folder))
- [makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder))

Lastly, the suggested solutions given in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696514/how-do-i-copy-move-a-file-to-a-folder-in-google-apps-script) might also help.