# Adding copy file to Google App Script code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, timeout

I get this code from other answer from StackOverflow to show all folders from RootFolder without timeout error.
It works very well !.
I must run to loop on all folders and subfolders. Its great

Now I want to copy all contents showed with `function processFile(file,path)` into a destination folder

Can someone guide me to do it ?

Thanks a lot

```
function main() {
    var _RootFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById('Replace with root FolderID')
    processRootFolder(_RootFolder) 
}


function processRootFolder(rootFolder) {
    MAX_RUNNING_TIME_MS = 1 * 60 * 1000;
    var RECURSIVE_ITERATOR_KEY = "RECURSIVE_ITERATOR_KEY";

    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

    // [{folderName: String, fileIteratorContinuationToken: String?, folderIteratorContinuationToken: String}]
    var recursiveIterator = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty(RECURSIVE_ITERATOR_KEY));
    if (recursiveIterator !== null) {
        // verify that it's actually for the same folder
        if (rootFolder.getName() !== recursiveIterator[0].folderName) {
          console.warn("Looks like this is a new folder. Clearing out the old iterator.");
          recursiveIterator = null;
        } else {
          console.info("Resuming session.");
        }
    }
    if (recursiveIterator === null) {
        console.info("Starting new session.");
        recursiveIterator = [];
        recursiveIterator.push(makeIterationFromFolder(rootFolder));
    }

    while (recursiveIterator.length > 0) {
        recursiveIterator = nextIteration(recursiveIterator, startTime);

        var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        var elapsedTimeInMS = currTime - startTime;
        var timeLimitExceeded = elapsedTimeInMS >= MAX_RUNNING_TIME_MS;
        if (timeLimitExceeded) {
            PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty(RECURSIVE_ITERATOR_KEY, JSON.stringify(recursiveIterator));
            console.info("Stopping loop after '%d' milliseconds. Please continue running.", elapsedTimeInMS);
            return;
        }
    }

    console.info("Done running");
    PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().deleteProperty(RECURSIVE_ITERATOR_KEY);
}

// process the next file or folder
function nextIteration(recursiveIterator) {
    var currentIteration = recursiveIterator[recursiveIterator.length-1];
    if (currentIteration.fileIteratorContinuationToken !== null) {
        var fileIterator = DriveApp.continueFileIterator(currentIteration.fileIteratorContinuationToken);
        if (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
            // process the next file
            var path = recursiveIterator.map(function(iteration) { return iteration.folderName; }).join("/");
            processFile(fileIterator.next(), path);
            currentIteration.fileIteratorContinuationToken = fileIterator.getContinuationToken();
            recursiveIterator[recursiveIterator.length-1] = currentIteration;
            return recursiveIterator;
          } else {
            // done processing files
            currentIteration.fileIteratorContinuationToken = null;
            recursiveIterator[recursiveIterator.length-1] = currentIteration;
            return recursiveIterator;
          }
    }

  if (currentIteration.folderIteratorContinuationToken !== null) {
      var folderIterator = DriveApp.continueFolderIterator(currentIteration.folderIteratorContinuationToken);
      if (folderIterator.hasNext()) {
          // process the next folder
          var folder = folderIterator.next();
          recursiveIterator[recursiveIterator.length-1].folderIteratorContinuationToken = folderIterator.getContinuationToken();
          recursiveIterator.push(makeIterationFromFolder(folder));
          return recursiveIterator;
      } else {
          // done processing subfolders
          recursiveIterator.pop();
          return recursiveIterator;
      }
  }

  throw "should never get here";
}

function makeIterationFromFolder(folder) {
    return {
        folderName: folder.getName(), 
        fileIteratorContinuationToken: folder.getFiles().getContinuationToken(),
        folderIteratorContinuationToken: folder.getFolders().getContinuationToken()
    };
}

function processFile(file, path) {
    console.log(path + "/" + file.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to copy in apps script is using the makeCopy() function:

```
file.makeCopy("new name", folder);
```

Here you will define the file which you will copy and the ID of the destination folder. Add the following function to your script:

```
function copyToFolder(file){
  var destinationFolderId = DriveApp.getFolderById("ID of Destination Folder")
  file.makeCopy("New File Name", destinationFolderId);
}
```

Then add this to your function main function:

```
function nextIteration(recursiveIterator) {
    var currentIteration = recursiveIterator[recursiveIterator.length-1];
    if (currentIteration.fileIteratorContinuationToken !== null) {
        var fileIterator = DriveApp.continueFileIterator(currentIteration.fileIteratorContinuationToken);
        if (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
            // process the next file
            var path = recursiveIterator.map(function(iteration) { return iteration.folderName; }).join("/");
            processFile(fileIterator.next(), path);
            copyToFolder(fileIterator.next()) //ADDED
            currentIteration.fileIteratorContinuationToken = fileIterator.getContinuationToken();
            recursiveIterator[recursiveIterator.length-1] = currentIteration;
            return recursiveIterator;
          } else {
            // done processing files
            currentIteration.fileIteratorContinuationToken = null;
            recursiveIterator[recursiveIterator.length-1] = currentIteration;
            return recursiveIterator;
          }
    }
```

##### References:

- [How do I copy & move a file to a folder in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696514/how-do-i-copy-move-a-file-to-a-folder-in-google-apps-script)
- [makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopy)

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry but I can not add formated code.
Thanks a lot @logan for your answer. But I get an error with the function  


`
copyToFolder(file){
    var destinationFolderId = "ID of Destination Folder"
    file.makeCopy("New File Name", destinationFolderId);
}
`
I change it to


`
copyToFolder(file){
    var destinationFolderId = DriveApp.getFolderbyID("ID of Destination Folder")
    file.makeCopy(file/getName()", destinationFolderId);
}
`
And it works, but of course, this scripts do no create folders and subfolders to put the files. 
Is possible do it ?

Comment: Hi @OmarPoch sorry I have miscopied the sample code to my answer. I have edited it to be changed to ` var destinationFolderId = DriveApp.getFolderbyID("ID of Destination Folder")`. For your situation where you want to createfolders and subfolders for the files. There is function where you can create folders and subfolders, where then you will add the your copy function. You may post it as a new question. I think that totally belongs to a different question as mentioned in this post is only to copy to a destination folder. Thanks